# Sorry, the requested view was not found in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I created an extension in TYPO3 7.6, and this appears, but when I click in the extension shows the following message:

**Sorry, the requested view was not found.**

**The technical reason is: No template was found. View could not be resolved for action "mod" in class**

Comment: No one will be able to help unless you give us more info or possibly a screenshot? What appears? Where do you click? What do you click? Have you used the extension builder? What Action would you expect to be called?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a `modAction()` in your `ExampleController`, you need to have a `Mod.html` template in the folder `Resources/Private/Templates/Example/` of the same extension because this is what fluid will render by default.

The exception idicates that this template does not exist.

Comment: I solved this, the problem is, the module Backend only render my .html if it is inside Administration Folder, but thanks for you answer!

And sorry for  my bad English!